# How set null a variable from session when the user leaves a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to  set one variable from session to null

```
Session["my_variable"] = null;
```

I tried with OnUnload like this

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnUnload(e);

       Session["my_variable"] = null;
    }
```

but it doesn't work right, it sets the variable while the user is on page but I want to set it null whet is leaves page

Comment: Do you mean if the user in the same web site, but in a different page??

Comment: @huMpty duMpty  in the same web site

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743447/how-does-one-discard-a-session-variable-while-closing-web-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function/event will be fired as soon as page is served to client, because it is a server side event. You might use Viewstate but still it cannot be implemented as navigation does not send any event to server while clientside scripting can help.

This functionality can be implemented by java script on-unload event. You have to send a request to server to remove or put null in particular session value ( as session is key-value object ).
 Your question is best explained at [Asp Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1202732.aspx)

But be careful. This event might fire only on navigation by some browser. you might have to do some code-work to implement what you want.

Comment: Note that that javascript onunload also fires on postbacks!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you are making use of ViewState inplace of Session Variable.

viewstate variable automatically get removed once you leave page

here is example how to use it

```
protected DataSet MyDataSet
{
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["MyDataSet"] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return (DataSet)ViewState["MyDataSet"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["MyDataSet"] = value;
    }
}
```